# KnpPaginatorBundle sort on join query

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a problem with the sort of bundle in question when I pass a join query customized.
My main purpose is to reduce the queries run in when a pagination of 20 results, it performs more than 30 queries.

But with a predefined query with joins other various tables "normally" is reduced to 2 queries, of course, with a saving of performance that will not hurt!

The problem arises with the KnpPaginatorBundle, where there seems to use my running the same query the 30 queries.

**Controller**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new SoundFilterType());
    if (!is_null($response = $this->saveFilter($form, 'sound', 'sound'))) {
        return $response;
    }

    $qb = $em->getRepository('AcmeSoundBundle:Soundtrack')->findAllJoin();
    $paginator = $this->filter($form, $qb, 'sound');


    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'paginator' => $paginator,
    );
}

/**
 * @param QueryBuilder $qb
 * @param string       $name
 */
protected function addQueryBuilderSort(QueryBuilder $qb, $name)
{
     $alias = current($qb->getDQLPart('from'))->getAlias();
     if (is_array($order = $this->getOrder($name))) {
         $qb->orderBy($alias . '.' . $order['field'], $order['type']);
     }
}

/**
 * Filter form
 *
 * @param  FormInterface  $form
 * @param  QueryBuilder   $qb
 * @return SlidingPagination
 */
protected function filter(FormInterface $form, QueryBuilder $qb, $name)
{
    if (!is_null($values = $this->getFilter($name))) {
       if ($form->bind($values)->isValid()) {
           $this->get('lexik_form_filter.query_builder_updater')->addFilterConditions($form, $qb);
       }
    }

    $count = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                ->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(c) FROM AcmeSoundBundle:Sound c')
                ->getSingleScalarResult();

    // possible sorting
    $this->addQueryBuilderSort($qb, $name);
    return $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($qb->getQuery()->setHint('knp_paginator.count', $count), $this->getRequest()->query->get('page', 1), 20, array('distinct' => false));

}
```

**Query**

```
public function findAllJoin()
{        
     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
     $query = $qb->select('u')
          ->from('AcmeSoundBundle:Sound', 'u')
          ->innerJoin('u.artists', 'a')
          ->leftJoin('u.versions', 'v')
          ->leftJoin('v.instruments', 'i')
          ->addOrderBy('u.dataIns', 'ASC');
}
```

Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/Lughino/6358896

I do not understand why it does not use my query ..

Any idea?

### **EDIT:**

For this problem I found the error:

```
public function findAllJoin()
{        
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
    $query = $qb->select('u, a, v, i')
      ->from('AcmeSoundBundle:Sound', 'u')
      ->innerJoin('u.artists', 'a')
      ->leftJoin('u.versions', 'v')
      ->leftJoin('v.instruments', 'i')
      ->addOrderBy('u.dataIns', 'ASC');
}
```

instead:

```
public function findAllJoin()
{        
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');
    $query = $qb->select('u')
      ->from('AcmeSoundBundle:Sound', 'u')
      ->innerJoin('u.artists', 'a')
      ->leftJoin('u.versions', 'v')
      ->leftJoin('v.instruments', 'i')
      ->addOrderBy('u.dataIns', 'ASC');
}
```

The problem now is that if I select a column to sort the I shows only one result, and even when I do the sort fails, in fact the results are not sorted at all.

Is there something I'm missing?

### **EDIT2**

Solved!
If I set my two are instantiated from from and messed with for that!
In this way:

```
public function findAllJoin()
{        
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
   $query = $qb->select('u, a, v, i')
               ->innerJoin('u.artists', 'a')
               ->leftJoin('u.versions', 'v')
               ->leftJoin('v.instruments', 'i')
               ->addOrderBy('u.dataIns', 'ASC');
}
```

The problem is solved!

Comment: old post, but it saved my day ;) still missing in the official documentation, how to use joins ...

Comment: On Symfony 5 and saved mine too, thanks *a lot*! 20 queries less, half the time to query them...